# Click anywhere but on the element to hide it w/ if-statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement

**SOLUTION BELOW**

I've read through most questions around here concerning this concept, but I can't seem to get it to work with an if-statement. Any help?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2udYp/)

```
$("button").click(function () {
  $("div").fadeToggle("fast");
});

if ($("div").is(":visible")) {
  $(document).click(function () {
    $("div").fadeToggle("fast");
  });

  $("div").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
}
```

So, the button should toggle the div. When the div is toggled (i.e. `:visible`) the div should only be toggled back (not visible) by clicking anywhere on the page, but not when clicking on the div itself.

### Solution

I combined [Diabolic's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622606/click-anywhere-but-on-the-element-to-hide-it-w-if-statement/14622853#answer-14622841) and [Kevin Bowersox's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622606/click-anywhere-but-on-the-element-to-hide-it-w-if-statement/14622853#answer-14623359) into [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/2udYp/13/).

```
$("button").click(function (e) {
    $("div").fadeToggle("fast");
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$(document).click(function (e) {
    if($("div").is(":visible") && !$("div").is(e.target)) {
        $("div").fadeOut("fast");
    }
});
```

Comment: @Sarfaraz the link is working. See my edit.

Comment: Your solution works fine for me. I decided to place the document event listener inside the button event listener function and used `$(document).unbind('click')` when the if statement comes back true to stop further click events being unnecessarily captured in future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Javascript**

```
$("button").click(function (e) {
  $("div").fadeToggle("fast");
});

$(document).mouseup(function(event){
    var target = $("#no-mod");
    if(!target.is(event.target) && !$("button").is(event.target) && target.is(":visible")){
       $("div").fadeToggle("fast");
    }else{
      return false;
    }
});
```

**HTML**

```
<button>Click me</button>
<div id="no-mod"></div>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/2udYp/9/

Comment: This has the problem that clicking the button after the div is visible, will trigger fadeToggle twice (once in document mouseup, once in button click). So, it will always fade out and fade in again.

Comment: I've found some strange behaviour: click the button to toggle. Then, click very fast outside the div. It will keep toggling the div.

Comment: Never mind my previous comment. Solved that. I have used a solution, combining yours with Diabolic's. See my first post. Also, do you really need that else-statement?

Comment: Strangely enough, I can't seem to implement this. See this link: http://bramvanroy.be/webdevs/index.html Click on "Meer +" in the secondary menu. A sub menu will apear. But clicking on it will make it disappear, which should not happen!

Answer (score 2):

kindly check this update of your code :

```
$("button").click(function (e) {
  $("div").fadeToggle("fast");
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$("div").click(function (e) {    
  $("div").fadeIn("fast");
     e.stopPropagation();
});
 $(document).click(function (e) {
    $("div").fadeToggle("fast");
      e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

Comment: No, I don't want ot to hide when you click on the div itself.

Comment: Bare in mind when using e.stopPropagation(); it can have knock on affects to other parts of javascript running on your page

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be more like this;

```
$("button").click(function (e) {
    $("div").fadeToggle("fast");
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});

$(document).click(function () {
    if($("div").is(":visible")) {
        $("div").fadeToggle("fast");
    }
});

$("div").click(function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```

Why?

Because you are not binding your events in the runtime. You're doing it within a statement which is not happening instantly and when it happens it is just creating an event, not running it immediately.

I've tried to edit your code as less as I can. :)

**Additional Info:** And use stopImmediatePropagation() instead of stopPropagation() to be sure no other event is going to be executed after that line.

Comment: And what about every other element, will he have have to stopImmediatePropagation() in them as well?

Comment: If you are not going to bind your events to that wide scope, it is not needed. It is just needed for the object itself and the object that is going to show it.

Comment: So, does every other element being referenced in his code in the future require a `stopPropagation();` in order for this to continue to work? - Let's say he adds another div called `#div2` - to the example above. Will he need to add `stopPropagation()` to this?

Comment: In this code everything else than the <button> and the <div> object (and the objects inside in that <div>) will cause the <div> disappear as long as the <div> is visible in simple words. He is not going to need stopPropagation after every event.

Edited my comment after reading your edit to your comment.

Comment: So OP can add a `<div id="div2"></div>` to his code, and he won't need to put an `e.stopImmediatePropagation()` in the above jQuery *for $("div2")? Just a simple **yes** or **no**? Trying to decide to upvote or not - we're all here to help the op, so yes or no.

Comment: I believe that this question may work, but is least scalable out of all the answers. I don't want OP using this if he has to **repeat code** in order to continue his work. Don't take it personally.

Comment: What part of "He is not going to need stopPropagation after every event." is hard to understand really? stopPropagation and stopImmediatePropagation is ONLY NEEDED FOR the button and the object that is going to be shown by that button. NOTHING ELSE. You're making me repeat myself.

Comment: Thanks! You didn't state it before (may have edited your comment, but I didn't see this); you were being very vague up until then. This is clear!

Comment: This works as expected, indeed. Thanks! I do fear for performance though. Because, every time a user clicks anywhere in the document, jQuery will have to check whether or not the div is visible. But I suppose there's no other way?

Comment: You are right and I don't think it'll cause any performance problems as long as you do not do that 1000 times in a second. It'll be unnoticeable difference even if you can find another way to do that.

Comment: Thanks. (+1) I have used a solution that combines your solution with Kevin Bowersox's. See my first post. :)

Answer (score 0):

You *don't* really need a lot of IF statements for this one. Pseudo-code wise, you want clicking anywhere on the `<body>` to hide the button, but clicking on the button to do something else. You can use `.click()` or `.on('click', function() . . .` to achieve this.

See the code below:

```
$('body').click(function(e) {
    if(e.target.id == "btn"){
        $('#box').show();
    }
    else
    {
        if(e.target.id !== 'box')
        {
            $('#box').hide();
        }
    }
});
```

... and your markup:

```
<body>
    <button id='btn'>Click me</button>
    <div id = "box" width="50px" height="50px"></div>
</body>
```

You can check this out at this [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/2udYp/14/)

I would like to say a few important things. If you're creating the element dynamically, don't use `.live()` as it's depreciated. Use `.on()` which can be found [in the docs here](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

---

Other than that, the above code works flawlessly. I would like to point out that this answer is **scalable** - with others you *may need to place `e.preventDefault()` or similar in every element you reference with a `.click()` in your code. This code does not require any changes in the future.

Comment: @BramVanroy Click the red square (or outside it I think, as that's the body) - the button disappears. Click the button, nothing happens, right?

Comment: Please re-read my start post, I don't want to remove the button.

Comment: Thank you for your effort. It is not what I need though. First of all, you'll need window instead of body and show should be toggle to make sure that the button can hide it again.

Comment: @BramVanroy No worries - are you not using <body> at all? (I assumed 100% valid markup) :) Also, toggle() is less accurate than performing each action individually with a check - it's generally safer for client-side stuff.

Comment: Ofcourse I do, but the body does not necessarily cover the whole window, hence it is better to use window. :)

Answer (score 0):

Is this the behaviour you were looking for ???

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    $("div").fadeToggle("fast");
      e.stopPropagation();
 });
$("button").click(function (e) {
  $("div").fadeToggle("slow");
  e.stopPropagation();
});
$("div").click(function (e) {    
      e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Modified Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2udYp/6/)

Edited Code:

```
$(document).click(function (e) {
    $("div").fadeToggle("fast");
    e.stopPropagation();

    if($("div").is(':visible')){
        $("div").click(function (e) {    
            e.stopPropagation();
        });
    }
});
$("button").click(function (e) {
    $("div").fadeToggle("slow");
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Modified Fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/2udYp/10/)

Edit 2:

```
(document).click(function (e) {
   if($("div").is(':visible')){
         $("div").fadeToggle("fast");
    }
    $("div").click(function (e) {    
       e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
$("button").click(function (e) {
  $("div").fadeToggle("slow");
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Modified Fiddle 3](http://jsfiddle.net/2udYp/12/)

Comment: No, because it does not take the visibility of the div into account.

Comment: This toggles the div even when it's not visible when clicking outside the div.

Comment: Thanks, but it's solved already. Sorry for the work you put in it.