# DIV appears when clicked, I want it to disappear when clicked anywhere on the screen using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Shows and hides the .box class

```
$('.popup').on('click', function(){
    $('.box').toggleClass('show');
});
```

THE CSS

```
.show {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: You want to attach a `click` handler to the `body` and check the clicked element to determine if it's inside or outside of your popup--if outside `toggleClass('show')`. Alternatively, you could include an overlay behind your popup and listen for the click event on that.

Comment: Possible duplicated question.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/152975/how-to-detect-a-click-outside-an-element

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14622606/click-anywhere-but-on-the-element-to-hide-it-w-if-statement

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/714471/jquery-hide-element-when-clicked-anywhere-on-the-page